# Creating a DateFrame from a list, with 1 column and n rows

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

For some reason when I try to create a dataframe (call it system_mean) from this list which has 288 entries in it the dataframe shape is (1,288), but when I create a dataframe from a dummy list with 3 entries the dataframe shape is (3,1). I am trying to add the system_mean dataframe to another dataframe whose shape is (288,15), so it has to be the same shape.

```
import pd
L = ['Thanks You', 'Its fine no problem', 'Are you sure']
df3 = pd.DataFrame(L) 

system_mean = [Final_Price.mean(axis=1)]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(system_mean)
```

note; Final_Price is a dataframe whose shape is (288,15), and I am taking the mean of each row. So Final_Price.mean(axis=1) returns a list with 288 entries.

Why does it the same command return the list in columns for one list, and return it in rows for another list?

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is the list L is horizontal when it is printed in the terminal, and system_mean is printed vertically because it has an index of timestamps. If this is the problem how can I fix it?

Comment: what do you mean by `add the system_mean dataframe to another dataframe`?Add every data in cell or concatenate?If you want add each cell,the shape need to be exactly same.

Comment: I was concatenating the (288,1) dataframe onto the end of the (288,15) dataframe. Thanks for bringing that up

Answer (score 1):

`Final_Price.mean(axis=1)` is not a list but a pandas Series. By doing `[Final_Price.mean(axis=1)]` you are putting it inside a list and that's what is causing the DataFrame to be horizontal.

Compare the following:

```
L = pd.Series(['Thanks You', 'Its fine no problem', 'Are you sure'])

pd.DataFrame(L)
Out: 
                     0
0           Thanks You
1  Its fine no problem
2         Are you sure

pd.DataFrame([L])
Out: 
            0                    1             2
0  Thanks You  Its fine no problem  Are you sure
```

So you can solve it by removing the brackets or you can also use `Final_Price.mean(axis=1).to_frame('name_of_the_column`).

Comment: thanks, thought it was probably something silly like that